# not understanding regex pattern for matching an integer

Tags: regular-expression

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options

> -n
> --quiet
> --silent
> -e script
> --expression=script Add the commands in script to the set of commands to be run while processing the input.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593320/insert-field-separator-to-arrange-and-capture-value-in-variable-in-shell-script/14593411#14593411

like this answer:

```
echo $'For example:\nThis is counter1 1000\nthis counter2 2000\n
     this counter3 is higher value 3000\ndone.\n' |
  sed -ne 's/^.* \([0-9]\{1,99\}\)/\1/p'
```

I understand `([0-9]\{1,99\}\)` refer to pattern integer.
`^`refer to beginning of a the string.
`.*`  refer to 1 or more character.

But overall, I am still confused with
`sed -ne 's/^.* \([0-9]\{1,99\}\)/\1/p'`

Comment: Not clear on precisely what you're not clear on : )  But here's a useful [resource for regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html)

Comment: As stated [in the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/685621/338177) `.*` means **0** or more characters. For 1 or more, you need `.+` (with `-E`) or `.\+`. And `^` matches the beginning of the **line**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(First, this is not a bash integer regex pattern. `sed` is handling the regex and has nothing to do with bash)*

So I understand that you are unable to figure out the regex in `sed -ne 's/^.* \([0-9]\{1,99\}\)/\1/p'`

Let's make it simpler. The equivalent code would be `sed -E -ne 's/^.* ([0-9]{1,99})/\1/p'`

The `-E` enables extended (modern) regex and you won't have to escape stuff using `\`

The `s/pattern/replacement/` operator looks for a string matching the regex pattern in the left side and replaces it with the string on the right.

Now, let's focus on `/^.* ([0-9]{1,99})/`

- `^` matches at the beginning of the line
- `.*` matches any character 0 or more times
- (space) matches a single space character
- `[0-9]{1,99}` matches any digits occurring a minimum of 1 time to a max of 99; so any number with a length of 1 to 99

`([0-9]{1,99})` is in parentheses which means sed will "capture" this substring and use it in the replacement part where `\1` was used.

Comment: Note that it's functionally equivalent to `sed -ne 's/^.* \([0-9]\)/\1/p'`. The interval operator serves no purpose here as there's nothing that needs to be found after that sequence of digits. `[0-9]{1,99}` would also match on the first 99 digits of a 300 digit number. It would make a difference in `sed -ne 's/^.* \([0-9]\{1,99\}\)$/\1/p'` for instance where the `$` matches on the end of the subject.

Comment: I understand `s/pattern/replacement/` but what does the last character `p` refer to?

Comment: `p` is a sed directive meaning print whatever was matched.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: But yur expression only matches one digit.